How to serve images from backend to frontend
I have an application with following three different docker containers:-
Frontend(react)
Back-end(django)
Nginx for serving static files from frontend,
I am trying to access nginx website in Kubernetes (minikube).from
minikube service my-service

all other data is being served from backend container but only image is not being sent
Can someone please help.
debug is true and
MEDIA_URL = ‘/media/’
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR ,“/app/media”)

I have kept the name of django app as django-service,
should I change the following lines in setttings.py file to django-service as well ?
ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'

here is entrypoint.sh file with same name
#!/bin/sh

gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

and following is deploment resources
# Django Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: django-container
        image: ash414/e-cart-backend:v1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000

# Django Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: django-service
  labels:
    app: django-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: django-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000

# Nginx Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-app
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        # Not working images
        # image: e-cart-nginx:latest
        # image: ash414/e-cart-nginx:v1.0v
        # image: ash414/e-cart-nginx-dj4:v1.0
        image: ash414/nginx-app4:v1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

# Nginx Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

# NodePort Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30007


Just FYI 1:

STATIC_FILES and MEDIA_FILES are two different things, and should
reside in two different directories. The collectstatic command has
nothing to do with media files.
To make media files available, you need to ensure your webserver is
configured to serve the directory where those files are stored
(MEDIA_ROOT), and the urls are generated using the url attribute of
the filefield object and not using the static tag. See Model field
reference | Django documentation | Django and the examples at
Managing files | Django documentation | Django)

To serve static files like images, refer to this documentation -
Serving static files in production
This StackOverflow post might also help you - I can't show images in django
1. https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/static-files-and-newly-generated-images/24535/2

I have tried adding persistent volume and media file path , but still not working.
Any idea where should I look .
When I use inspection tool on chrome I can see the following path
<img class="MuiCardMedia-root MuiCardMedia-media MuiCardMedia-img css-1m86w4c" src="/media/images/IMG_20201112_204213.jpg" alt="test product">
http://127.0.0.1:52648/media/images/IMG_20201112_204213.jpg


